# SQL Server list from detail table

Tags: sql-server

Let us build 2 tables

```
create table School
(
IdSchool int not null PK,
Name     varchar(10) not null
)

create table Prof
(
IdSchool   int not null,
IdProf     int not null,
name       varchar (10)
PK (IdSchool, IdProf)
)
```

I would like to build query like this:

```
IdSchool, Prof.Name*
```

- prof name should be a list that consist of ALL the profs from the same school.

Now, I know it is not a problem to build a list with a procedure or function, but is there a way to build a query that can return this kind of a result.

P.S. query should return single line, so result table from *school left join prof* is not a result I want to achieve.

thx.

Comment: Please provide sample data with desired ouput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct Idschool, profs
FROM profs p1
CROSS APPLY
(
select substring((
    SELECT ',' + name 
    FROM profs p2    
    WHERE p1.Idschool = p2.Idschool
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),2,1000)
    as Profs    
) profs
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT IdSchool, Prof_name = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [name]
           FROM Prof b 
           WHERE b.IdProf = a.IdProf 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM Prof a
GROUP BY IdSchool
```

Comment: +1 for using the stuff command, found it fairly recently and love it!